# Working with python and django: my Status is not rendering on my views correctly

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So my goal is to show the status of the job application as a drop down with the default to 'applied' but the rest of the selection would be:  ('A', 'Applied'),
('B', 'In Progress'),
('C', 'Interview scheduled'),
('D', 'Interview complete'),
('E', 'Job Offer'),
('F', 'Incomplete'),
('G', 'Not Selected'),
('H', 'Unknown'),
But its not rendering correctly, any help?

Update: When I click 'Update Status' I get an error.
For "Status", the Job App form should not have an option to select status, but instead, automatically generate and assign a default value of "Applied", with the "date" attribute of status being the same as whatever "date" is put for Job_app

[image]

here are my models

```
class Job_application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateField('Date Applied')
    url = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        blank=True
        )
    requirements = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
        blank=True
        )
    notes = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
        blank=True
        )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'job_id': self.id}) #every model instance has its own method 
        #django will now render the detail page, 

class Attachment(models.Model): # will implement later with AWS if possible -CO
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    job_app = models.ForeignKey(Job_application, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Attachment for job_id: {self.job_id} @{self.url}'

class Status(models.Model):
  date = models.DateField('Date')

  STATUS = (
        ('A', 'Applied'),
        ('B', 'In Progress'),
        ('C', 'Interview scheduled'),
        ('D', 'Interview complete'),
        ('E', 'Job Offer'),
        ('F', 'Incomplete'),
        ('G', 'Not Selected'),
        ('H', 'Unknown'),
  )
 
  status = models.CharField(
    max_length=1,
    choices=STATUS,
    default=STATUS[0][0]
  )

  job_app = models.ForeignKey(Job_application, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
    # Nice method for obtaining the friendly value of a Field.choice
    return f"{self.get_status_display()}"

  # change the default sort
  class Meta:
    ordering = ['-date']
```

here are my views

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def jobs_index(request):
    # insert jobs model here
    jobs = Job_application.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date')
    return render(request, 'jobs/index.html', {'jobs': jobs})

def jobs_detail(request, job_id):
    # insert jobs model here
    job = Job_application.objects.get(id=job_id)
    status_form = StatusForm()
    status = Status.objects.filter(job_app=job_id).first()

    return render(request, 'jobs/detail.html', {
        'job': job,
        'status': status,
        'status_form': status_form,
    })

def signup(request):
    error_message = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            error_message = 'Invalid signup data - please try again'
    
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form, 'error_message': error_message })

class JobCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Job_application
    fields = ['name', 'company', 'location', 'date', 'url', 'requirements', 'notes']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class JobUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Job_application
    fields = ['name', 'company', 'location', 'date', 'url', 'requirements', 'notes']

class JobDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Job_application
    success_url = '/jobs/'

def add_status(request, job_id):
    form = StatusForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_status = form.save(commit=False)
        new_status.job_id = job_id
        new_status.save()
    
    return redirect('detail', job_id=job_id)
```

Here are my forms

```
from .models import Status

class StatusForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Status
        fields = ['date', 'status']
```

here is my detail.html

```
{% block content %}

<h1>Job Application Details</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <p><b>Job Title:</b> {{ job.name }}</p>
            <p><b>Company:</b> {{ job.company }}</p>
            <p><b>Location:</b> {{ job.location }}</p>
            <p><b>Date Applied:</b> {{ job.date }}</p>
            <p><b>Status:</b> {{ status }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-detail">
            <form action="{% url 'add_status' job.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ status_form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" value="Update Status" class="btn">
            </form>
            <table class="striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr><th>Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {% for status in job.status_set.all %}
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ status.date }}</td>
                      <td>{{ status.get_status_display}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h5>Requirements</h5>
            <p>
                {{ job.requirements }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h5>Notes</h5>
            <p>
               {{ job.notes }} 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'jobs_update' job.id %}">Edit</a>
    <a href="{% url 'jobs_delete' job.id %}">Delete</a>
</div>

<script>
    // create datepicker
    var dateEl = document.getElementById('id_date');
    M.Datepicker.init(dateEl, {
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      setDefaultDate: true,
      autoClose: true,
    });
  
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Define 'But its not rendering correctly...', add as update to the question.

Comment: i was able to define it more and added a picture.

Comment: Well this is probably related to what the content of  `StatusForm` and `jobs/detail.html` are? You will need to include them in your question.

Comment: HI adrian, I included them in my question. lol at this rate i wont get hired as a python dev haha

Comment: In the `card-content` section `status` is None, so I would not expect anything in the detail section either. I haven't followed this all the way through, though my first suspicion is that it has to do with `status = Status.objects.filter(job_app=job_id).first()` in `jobs_detail` view. `job_app` is a FK field, you should be setting that to an instance of  `Job_application` in this case `job`, not what I presume is an  integer(`job_id`).

Comment: adrian i got it thankyou